# Hypothesis Testing w/ Year Indicator Variables

Tags: hypothesis-testing, stata

This is a fairly basic question, but I was hoping that you all could help me nail down the language of this test.

I have six years of data in the sample and the  following general model:

$$y = b_0 + b_1 x + b_2 \text{year1} + b_3 \text{year2} + b_4 \text{year3} + \epsilon$$

y = continuous outcome variable
x = continuous independent variable
year1 = indicator variable set to one for year1 observations, zero otherwise
year2 = indicator variable set to one for year2 observations, zero otherwise
year3 = indicator variable set to one for year3 observations, zero otherwise

If I want to test whether the early period (year1, year2, year3) is different from the late period, then which of the following tests will I conduct (assuming year4, year5, year6 is in the intercept)?

(using Stata notation)
Option A: test year1 = year2 = year3 = 0
Option B: test year1 + year2 + year3 = 0

What incremental information does each test provide (i.e., how are the two tests different)?

Comment: Neither option describe your hypothesis. But your hypothesis is not well articulated. What does it mean that the early period "is the same as" the late period?

Comment: I want to know whether the impact of the early period on the outcome variable is different from the effect of the later period on the outcome.  One way to do this would be to just create an indicator variable for early (if year1,  year2, or year3 is one) and examine the significance of that coefficient. I want to have separate year variables because I want to make statements about each year individually and all of the years collectively.

Comment: why is "year" an indicator variable? Are these data in a long format with one observation per year? That would be wrong because you're ignoring dependence between years. It sounds like an interrupted time series approach is more appropriate. I don't think there's enough info to answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're on the right track with the idea of testing either a subset or a linear combination of coefficients.

1. "Year1" is the *regressor* and $b_1$ is the *coefficient*. We don't construct hypothesis around the regressors, they are a vector of observations that have no random properties. $b_1$ is a linear function of the outcome and *does* have random properties, so it's appropriate to construct hypothesis tests about its quantity.
2. If you measured the later periods, you should include their effects to have a fully specified distributed lag model.
3. The hypothesis of no heterogeneity (your option A) would be $$\mathcal{H_0}: b_2=b_3=b_4=b_5=b_6=b_7 \quad \text{vs}$$ 
   $$\mathcal{H_a}: (b_2=b_3=b_4) \ne (b_5=b_6=b_7) $$
   The hypothesis of no cumulative trend would be $$\mathcal{H_0}: b_2+b_3+b_4=b_5+b_6+b_7 \quad \text{vs}$$ 
   $$\mathcal{H_a}: (b_2+b_3+b_4) \ne (b_5+b_6+b_7) $$

Comment: Why introduce six parameters in either instance where two will do?  (BTW, please check the subscripts on your hypotheses--I think you want some of them to be $\mathcal{H}_A$ instead of $\mathcal{H}_0.$)

Comment: @whuber because the actual distribution of $year_i$ (whatever that is) may flucatuate and one loses precision and (worse) introduces bias in the presence of trend without having a fully specified distributed lag model.

Comment: Thank you--this is helpful. The reason that I set the model up without all of the lags is because of my specific research question. In this case, the first three years are defined as "early" and the last three years are defined as "late." I want to compare the first three years to the last three years (i.e., is the collective impact of the first three years different from the last three years?). Assuming I reject H0 in both cases, aren't my conclusions the same (i.e., the early years are different from the late years)?

Comment: I see--thank you.  Your model looks more appropriate for the research question.  I see how all six parameters are needed for option A.

Comment: @Tots Let me expand on why the language is confusing. We have a year (variable) and a beta (coefficient). Suppose for year4 to year6, the variable values were 0. What does that mean? For instance, if I studied whether a new fertilizer boosted crop yield and measured rainfall (yearly as "year"), and my crop yield was 0 because there was drought... would I say my fertilizer kills plants? Or would I have no power to say if the fertilizer did anything?

Comment: @AdamO Wouldn't the year indicator variables capture the effect of the years when there was a drought? In this case, I'm interested in testing the impact of early/late tenure on the outcome variable. I want to separate out the first three years specifically because I want to test for differences between each year (i.e., b2 = b3, b2 = b4, b3=b4) and I want to collectively test whether b2,b3, and b4 are different from the later years (in the intercept). My main question is whether testing b2=b3=b4 and b2+b3+b4=0 lead me to the same conclusion (the early period is different from the late period).

Comment: @Tots not if you omit the variables from the analysis. This is called aliasing. It becomes impossible for you to tell whether $year_4, year_5, year_6$ were low or whether $b_5, b_6, b_7$ were close to 0.

Comment: @AdamO If all of the years in the sample are evenly distributed (~16 percent of the sample for each year--I forgot to mention this). What is the difference between these issues? _year4,year5,year6 were low or whether b5,b6,b7 were close to 0_. The impact of year4, year5, and year6 is is low (isn't that the same as saying that b5-b7 are close to zero)?

Comment: @Tots no. That's precisely why we need a model. But maybe we're all confused now. Your edits don't make sense to me. Are these data in a long format or something?

Comment: @AdamO I basically have a panel dataset. Year1 gets set to one if it's the first year in the sample, zero otherwise. Year2 gets set to one if it's the second year in the sample, zero otherwise. Year3 gets set to one for the third year in the sample, zero otherwise. Years4-Year6 aren't distinctly created and are therefore in the intercept. The occurrence of each year isn't low. I have six years in the sample and the number of first year observations is roughly the same as the number of sixth year observations.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/94257/discussion-between-adamo-and-tots).